# NativeScript: Which TabViewItem is active

Tags: nativescript

in XML I have a TabView with two TabViewItems in NativeScript. Each one has it's own title. In my JavaScript code I now want to know which TabViewItem is active at the moment. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `selectedIndexChanged` event to handle, when the selected Tab has been changed. - http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_tab_view_.tabview.html#selectedindexchangedevent. Examlpe - https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/tab-view#using-selectedindexchanged-changed-event

Comment: Yeah I tried this already, but it wasn't working. I forgot to export it :p Thx.